# Mongo DB document insertion through a script

Tags: json, mongodb, insert

I am trying to insert 100 documents into my MongoDB through the mongo shell. I wrote the below loop, but it gives me a syntax error that ";" is missing.

I am not sure where it is missing exactly.

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){ 
    db.noss.insert{(a:i,b:i+1)}; 
}
```

Comment: Switch  curly brackets and parenthesis

Comment: are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Thanks Sagar, yes it worked after switching curly brackets and parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Switching curly brackets and parenthesis worked. The final code is :

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){ 
    db.noss.insert({a:i,b:i+1}); 
}
```